# Get the Session info from Request.GetResponse()

Tags: asp.net, session, getresponse

I have an aplication that loads many asp.net pages and in every loop I need to take some information from the Sesion of the loaded page.

How can I do that?

example:

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
//How to get the Session from response???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Session state object is on the server.

Answer (score 1):

If this were even remotely possible it would be a security nightmare. Session data is protected in the server's memory and is only accessible to objects running within the application pool of the site. If you need information from a remote page in this manner, the remote page will have to be restructured to provide the information either through added headers or cookies.